# add a field in edit product page of prestashop admin

Tags: product, prestashop

I have add a field "mystock" in product table of prestashop database. Now i want to display/edit this filed in edit product page. It also be update when product will update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This process require some work around in steps. Below i have listed them.

1) Open classes/Product.php. Place **public $mystock;** in the class properties list, which you can see after the class is started.

2) Down the file, find **public static $definition = array(**  , it will be a long array. Find the **'fields' => array(** in it, and there you will see all the database fields placed with validation, data types etc. Place your mystock there in that array as another item and place the correct validations and data types like placed for other fields.

3) Now open **adminFolder/themes/default/template/controllers/products/informations.tpl** and place your field with the correct name and id in the appropriate place. Please note that the field name / id both should be same like the db field name and the one we added in the Products.php class.

Thats it,
Hope you understand the process and will make it work.

Thank you

Comment: Hi altafhussain, thanks for reply and it is useful for me, now i am facing new problem.
when i go to product edit it give me error "This field friendly URL is required at least in English (English)" and not show save button
help me

Comment: I want to tell you that i have add products in table directly

Comment: Link rewrite or any other required fields are only required for the default language of the site. I think you have added products, but did not added product details like link rewrite in the product_lang table, or if you have added them, then you did not addded them for the default langauge like english. Check that please

Answer (score 6):

this one works for me on prestashop 1.5.4

add a file Product.php to   \override\classes containing:

```
    <?php
    Product::$definition['fields']['mystock'] = array('type' => ObjectModel::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt');
    class Product extends ProductCore 
    { 
       public $mystock; 
    }
```

...supposing you need a field to enter a number.

then 3) of altafhussain's answer

don't forget to add your field to the DB, for number field:
ALTER TABLE `ps_product` ADD `mystock` INT NOT NULL;

Comment: this answer is better, you have better chances for a prestashop update not to break your functionality

Comment: THIS IS NOT WORKING if it's in the Module override classes! I did investigations for this, and it's definitely wrong :( `ps v1.5.6.1`

Answer (score 3):

I came across this article and build my component based on it and it seems to be cleanest solution: http://nemops.com/prestashop-products-new-tabs-fields/ basically it describes how to make a module, which adds multilingual field in custom panel on product editing page..

NO need to edit templates, core files or add override files.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks altafhussain.
You have to add your field to both 'products_shop' and 'products' tables.

```
ALTER TABLE ps_product_shop ADD `mystock` int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
ALTER TABLE ps_product ADD `mystock` int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

I'm using ps 1.6.0.6

Answer (score 1):

The best comprehensive solution in four steps is:

1) add a file Product.php to \override\classes containing:

```
<?php
Product::$definition['fields']['mystock'] = array('type' => ObjectModel::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedInt');
class Product extends ProductCore 
{ 
   public $mystock; 
}
```

2) open adminFolder/themes/default/template/controllers/products/informations.tpl and place your field with the correct name and id in the appropriate place.

3) delete file cache/class_index.php

4) add your field to the DB, for number field:

```
ALTER TABLE ps_product ADD mystock INT NOT NULL;
```

[Thanks to Bell418 for 1) and 4) and to Altaf Hussain for 2)]