# How can I add new custom field with products in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

I want to add a new custom field at products in back office and validate it with integer only. What have I done:

1. Firstly, I have added a new column in `ps_product` table named as `member_id` with default value 0.
2. Second, I put html in `prestashop_project_folder\admin\themes\default\template\controllers\products\informations.tpl`:

   ```
   <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="member_id">
               {l s='Enter Member Id'}
       </label>
       <div class="col-lg-5">
           <input type="text" id="memberId" name="memberId" value="{$product->memberId|default:''}" />
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Now, what can I do? What are the next steps?

Answer (score 1):

First, use Prestashop overrides to add your custom code:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors

To override admin templates, use: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+helpers+to+overload+a+back-office+template

Next step is to add your custom field in an override Product class (declare and add to definition array).

Don't forget to remove cache/class_index.php after each override.

Comment: Thanks Garry for your reply, but I have added new field like this way: [http://connectonline.in/new-filed-for-product-page-in-prestashop-1-6/][1] 
.May you please tell me is it right way or not.


  [1]: http://connectonline.in/new-filed-for-product-page-in-prestashop-1-6/

Comment: The right way is to override all changes, you will update your prestashop without problem.
Your tutorial like good, you should see your custom field in the product back office. No?

Question already posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475509/add-a-field-in-edit-product-page-of-prestashop-admin